# Cannot add security principles mainly SACL on WindowsApps directories and restore files. SID S-1-19-512-4096:(OI)(CI)(RX,D,WDAC,WO,WA)

Tags: security, backup, permissions, windows-11, access-control

I want to add the SACL of WindowsApp Folder. When i did icacls on the folder it shows something S-1-19-512-4096:(OI)(CI)(RX,D,WDAC,WO,WA) which is SACL i guess and i want to set this to other folder created by me inside the WindowsApp.
[ScreenShot Output of icacls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVJIW.png)

Looks like Windows protect files inside WindowsApps somehow besides normal access control lists. Even if I explicitly grant full access to everyone, files still unavailable to edit. icacls shows extra entity in ACL for S-1-19-512-4096 SID, that is not shown in GUI, maybe it related somehow.

and no one have permissions to restore them, change them, rename them delete them.

Is there any information's about that and how to disabled or change it or take over it, because is not let me restore some files after have been backup.

Comment: No!! This is mainly for editing permission through file explorer but i need to set sid S-1-19-512-4096 programmatically which is not even visible in gui but show by icacls

Comment: Where did you see file explorer in my answer in that link? Please read it through and adapt it to your case.